# Position a JavaScript block in an existing div area

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to remove the background image in the header area of [this](http://shoutkey.com/pliant) site and place a rectangular javascript ad on the right of the logo.  The various div blocks that the header area consists of are extremely confusing and any content I place next to the logo end up beneath it instead of on the right, even if it's a a few characters of text.  There seems to be plenty of room to the right of the logo, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing strange going on here; your logo element (`#rt-logo`) is a block element, which by default doesn't allow inline elements to be positioned next to it. You can either absolutely position your ad box - the parent div of class `.rt-omega` is relatively positioned, making this simple - or you could give `#rt-logo` either a `float: left;` or a `display: inline-block;` to do what you want.

That said, this is a very basic problem and you might want to take a look at a [css tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) or two. If you're going to spend any amount of time working on websites, it will be worth your while.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely need to go through a tutorial at some point.  Can you tell me how to push the ad all the way in the top-right corner of the .rt-omega div?

Comment: The answer is definitely in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: I'm sure you mean well by wanting to send everybody to school, but keep in mind that not everyone has time to go through a complete course in order to accomplish a short task that they may never need to do again

Comment: I understand that, Knocks, but you've asked a large number of very basic CSS-related questions in the last three weeks. While it is absolutely your prerogative to learn or not learn anything you wish, it *is* clear that you have an ongoing need for this information.

Comment: It's a little creepy that you're watching other users, and if by a "large number" you mean 2, then yes, I've asked a huge number of CSS questions, this being the third one in a month and a half.  That being said, this is a question-and-answer site, not a RTFM site, so I'd suggest you tune your response format accordingly or not respond at all.

Comment: I answered your question as asked. You are free to make whatever you want of it.